# Retrieving single order in my-orders.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to add a search form in my-orders.php where user can search the order table by inputing the order id.

Currently, I am retrieving all orders by 1 customer using get_posts:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
'numberposts' => $order_count,
'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
'post_status' => 'wc-quotes') ) );
```

Are there any way I can retrieve just an order by order id (value input in search bar)?

I am still new to WooCommerce so please pardon me if my explanation is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need first to add a **custom form** to your page because the Normal search bar will not work for that.

Here is a custom form using post method that you can use:

```
echo'<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Search an Order ID</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="orderid" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_trusted_list" value="Submit"/>
</form>';
```

Then as the hook filter **`woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query`** is included in your code that query the orders, you will use a custom hooked function, where the argument 'post__in' will filter the query with the given Order ID:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'search_orders_by_id', 20, 1 );
function search_orders_by_id( $args ){
    if( isset($_POST['orderid']) && is_numeric ($_POST['orderid']) ){
        $args['post__in'] = array(intval($_POST['orderid']));
    }
    return $args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> So you will get a filtered list only with the requested order.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wc_get_order` function and pass your `orderid` in param

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
```

Now you can use `$order_data`

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($order_data);
```

Reference

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order.html
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/composite-products-functions-reference/